# Apache Camel and MQTT: How to use simple language for e.g. topics?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Camel for wanting to push a resource to a topic.

The name of the topic is depending on the content of a resource.
For this one I've implemented the `choice` definition.

I've put the name of the generated topic in the header of the message:

```
final String resource = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
String topic = resource + ".get.request";
exchange.getIn().setHeader("topic", topic);
```

When it comes to the endpoint part of the Camel route, then I wanted to read and re-use the topic out of the exchanged message:

```
     // the logging shows everything up correctly, with both variants..
     .log("${header.topic} : " + simple("${header.topic}").getText())

     // this line is not woking, because the simple language fails here
     .to("mqtt:camelMqtt?publishTopicName=${header.topic}?host=" + mqttHost);
```

If I am putting a hard coded topic instead of the `${header.topic}`, then the message is published on the mqtt-topic.
As stated in the code, the `to(...)`sequence is not working with the Simple Language. 
How to solve that kind of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it out by myself...

The Simple Language is only evaluated IF the endpoint method `toD`is used.
Makes totally sense, because this is a dynamic endpoint or at least the parameters of this endpoint are variable.

full line from above:

```
.toD("mqtt:camelMqtt?publishTopicName=${header.topic}?host=" + mqttHost);
```